# Delete row in html table with checkbox using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need delete each row in html table using checkbox
Currently can delete row using link
I am using switch in my code in case delete query exist
**Code php**

```
     <tr class="<?php if($i%2 == 0) { echo 'even'; } else { echo 'odd'; } 
       ?>">
     <td><div class="grid_content sno"><span><?php echo $i; ?>
     </span>    </div></td>
            <td><div class="grid_content editable"><span><?php echo 
            $records['name_ar']; ?></span><input type="text" 
            class="gridder_input" 
            name="<?php echo encrypt("name_ar|".$records['id']); ?>" 
            value="<?php echo $records['name_ar']; ?>" /></div></td>
            <td><div class="grid_content editable"><span>
            <?php echo $records['name_en']; ?>
            </span><input type="text" class="gridder_input" 
            name="<?php echo encrypt("name_en|".$records['id']); ?>"
            value="<?php echo $records['name_en']; ?>" /></div></td>
            <td>
            <a href="<?php echo encrypt($records['id']); ?>"
             class="gridder_delete"><img src="images/delete.png" 
             alt="Delete" title="Delete" /></a>
             <input type="checkbox"  name="delete[]" 
           value="<?php echo    encrypt($records['id']); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     case "delete":
     $value     = decrypt($_POST['value']);               
     $query = mssql_query("DELETE FROM Job_creation WHERE id = '$value' ");
     break;
```

**code ajax**

```
// Function for delete the record
$('body').delegate('.gridder_delete', 'click', function(){
    var conf = confirm('Are you sure want to delete this record?');
    if(!conf) {
        return false;
    }
    var ThisElement = $(this);
    var UrlToPass = 'action=delete&value='+ThisElement.attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : UrlToPass,
        success: function() {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
```

Many thanks in advance for those who help me :)